# how can I set the theme dynamically at runtime to whole application

Tags: android, android-theme

I need to load a theme for all activities in my application programmatically.
For this purpose I use setTheme() method. But it works only for Activitity class, and does not not work to Application class.
How can I set the theme dynamically at runtime to whole application?

Answer (score 1):

For the rare cases where you're not using a themed activity context for your UI, consider using a [`ContextThemeWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html).

To use it where you normally would use `context`, make it `new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.your_theme_name)`.

Comment: can you give me an example of setting theme using ContextThemeWrapper?

Comment: Yes I have used in many occassions to e.g. style my dialogs successfully. Since there isn't a very specific question, it's hard to come up with a very specific answer.

Comment: So, what should I use istead of getApplicationContext().setTheme(R.style.Theme_Light)    ?